# Making a Clock in JavaScript using DIVs only

Tags: javascript, css

We have to build a clock in JavaScript using `div`s only, (`document.createElement()`). Somehow, I never get the positioning of the `div`s right. Currently, I'm already struggling to make the first DIV.

Sorry if I have mistakes in the calculation of the angles.

Are there any better ways to achieve this goal?

Now it looks a bit like this:
[image: My clock]

The red lines are representing the numbers of a clock (12 of them in total).

```js
window.onload = function drawclock() {
  var clock = this.document.getElementById("clock");
  var width = clock.offsetHeight;
  var radius = width / 2;

  for (var i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
    var element = document.createElement("DIV");
    addClass(element, "h");
    addClass(element, i);
    var deg = 30 * i;
    var x = Math.cos(deg * (180 / Math.PI)) * radius + radius;
    var y = Math.sin((90 - deg) * (180 / Math.PI)) * radius + radius;
    console.log(x + " " + y);
    element.style.position = "absolute";
    element.style.left = x + "px";
    element.style.top = y + "px";
    element.style.transform = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";
    clock.appendChild(element);
  }
}

function addClass(element, name) {
  var arr;
  arr = element.className.split(" ");
  if (arr.indexOf(name) == -1) {
    element.className += " " + name;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
}

#clock {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.h {
  width: 10px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: red
}

.m {
  width: 5px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="clock">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://cssanimation.rocks/clocks/

Comment: Thanks a lot, but my problem now is setting the right position of the divs. But thank you, i can use it for later :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a clock example made by [Eric Brewer](https://codepen.io/ebrewe) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ebrewe/pen/gxobvQ).

I have compiled SCSS and Pug keeping only the necessary parts of the code to make the clock work. This version doesn't require any JavaScript to run.

However, I have added some JavaScript code to make it start from a particular position. This can be achieved using the class [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to get the current date and setting the `animation-delay` CSS property with the property [`animationDelay`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_animationdelay.asp) for each clock arms.

Here is the working code:

```js
let setTime = function(date) {

  const delay = [
    date.getHours() * 3600 + date.getMinutes() * 60 + date.getSeconds(),
    date.getMinutes() * 60 + date.getSeconds(),
    date.getSeconds()
  ];

  [...document.querySelectorAll('.hand')].forEach((e, i) => e.style.animationDelay = `-${delay[i]}s`);

}

setTime(new Date())
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Main style for the clock */

.face {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 20px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.face:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
}


/* Numbers: styling and positioning */

.numbers {
  position: relative;
}

.number {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.number:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}

.number:nth-child(1) span {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-25deg);
}

.number:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(55deg);
}

.number:nth-child(2) span {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-55deg);
}

.number:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(85deg);
}

.number:nth-child(3) span {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-85deg);
}

.number:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(115deg);
}

.number:nth-child(4) span {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-115deg);
}

.number:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotate(145deg);
}

.number:nth-child(5) span {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-145deg);
}

.number:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(178deg);
}

.number:nth-child(6) span {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-175deg);
}

.number:nth-child(7) {
  transform: rotate(205deg);
}

.number:nth-child(7) span {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-205deg);
}

.number:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotate(235deg);
}

.number:nth-child(8) span {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-235deg);
}

.number:nth-child(9) {
  transform: rotate(265deg);
}

.number:nth-child(9) span {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-265deg);
}

.number:nth-child(10) {
  transform: rotate(295deg);
}

.number:nth-child(10) span {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-295deg);
}

.number:nth-child(11) {
  transform: rotate(325deg);
}

.number:nth-child(11) span {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-325deg);
}

.number:nth-child(12) {
  transform: rotate(355deg);
}

.number:nth-child(12) span {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-355deg);
}


/* Clock hands styling */

.hands {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.hand {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 120px;
  width: 10px;
  content: "";
  background: black;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  z-index: 4;
  animation: count 3600s linear infinite;
}

.hand:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-width: 10px 5px 41px;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  content: "";
}

.hand.hand-hour {
  height: 70px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%) rotate(30deg);
  animation: count 43200s linear infinite;
}

.hand.hand-second {
  height: 130px;
  width: 8px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%) rotate(60deg);
  z-index: 3;
  background: red;
  animation: count 60s linear infinite;
}

.hand.hand-second .body {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: "";
  background: red;
  z-index: 4;
}

.hand.hand-second:before {
  border-width: 10px 4px 41px;
  border-bottom-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
}


/* animation of the clock hands */

@keyframes count {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%) rotate(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%) rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%) rotate(270deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="watch">
  <div class="face">
    <div class="numbers">
      <div class="number number-1"><span>1</span></div>
      <div class="number number-2"><span>2</span></div>
      <div class="number number-3"><span>3</span></div>
      <div class="number number-4"><span>4</span></div>
      <div class="number number-5"><span>5</span></div>
      <div class="number number-6"><span>6</span></div>
      <div class="number number-7"><span>7</span></div>
      <div class="number number-8"><span>8</span></div>
      <div class="number number-9"><span>9</span></div>
      <div class="number number-10"><span>10</span></div>
      <div class="number number-11"><span>11</span></div>
      <div class="number number-12"><span>12</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hands">
      <div class="hand hand-hour"></div>
      <div class="hand hand-minute"></div>
      <div class="hand hand-second">
        <div class="body"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Simply set the current date in `date`, the JavaScript code will loop through the clock's arms and delay each animation. CSS animation will allow the clock to run continuously after page has been loaded.

This method is a lot more efficient than using a JavaScript function to compute the positions and move clock hands. CSS animations are way more powerful here.

---

### EDIT :

When you're programming a piece of code you should always start with a piece of paper and define what you want, how you will achieve it before starting typing. You have to have a plan before typing, otherwise, it will simply not work.

So as you told me you only want to position the number ticks (the original question wasn't that clear...). It's easier to have all ticks as black rectangles positioned in the center, set their `height` and `width`. So we have:

[image]

Then use the `transform` property to rotate each tick to the right angle: `0°`, `30°`, `60°`, `90°`, ..., `300°`, `330°` and `360°`. Use `rotate(x deg)`.

Lastly here's the [trick](https://css-tricks.com/left-and-right/#article-header-id-0) to the set the ticks' size correctly:
use a gradient to hide the part of the tick closer to the center so we only show the tip of each tick:

```
background: linear-gradient(
   to top, 
   #eee 0%, 
   #eee 80%, 
   black 80%, 
   black 100%
);
```

[image]

In the end you should have:

[image]

Combining this with the previous code to make the clock turn you get:

```js
let drawTicks = function() {

  for (let i = 1; i < 13; i++) {

    let el = document.createElement('div');
    el.setAttribute('class', `number number${i}`);
    el.style.transform = `rotate(${i*30}deg)`;

    document.querySelector('.numbers').appendChild(el);

  }

}; drawTicks()


let setTime = function(date) {

  const delay = [
    date.getHours() * 3600 + date.getMinutes() * 60 + date.getSeconds(),
    date.getMinutes() * 60 + date.getSeconds(),
    date.getSeconds()
  ];

  [...document.querySelectorAll('.hand')].forEach((e, i) => e.style.animationDelay = `-${delay[i]}s`);

}; setTime(new Date())
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Main style for the clock */

.face {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 20px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.face:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
}


/* Numbers: styling and positioning */

.numbers {
  position: relative;
}

.number {
  width: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient( to top, #eee 0%, #eee 80%, black 80%, black 100%);
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  font-size: 28px;
}

/* Clock hands styling */

.hands {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.hand {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 120px;
  width: 10px;
  content: "";
  background: black;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  z-index: 4;
  animation: count 3600s linear infinite;
}

.hand:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-width: 10px 5px 41px;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  content: "";
}

.hand.hand-hour {
  height: 70px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%) rotate(30deg);
  animation: count 43200s linear infinite;
}

.hand.hand-second {
  height: 130px;
  width: 8px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%) rotate(60deg);
  z-index: 3;
  background: red;
  animation: count 60s linear infinite;
}

.hand.hand-second:before {
  border-width: 10px 4px 41px;
  border-bottom-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
}


/* animation of the clock hands */

@keyframes count {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%) rotate(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%) rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%) rotate(270deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="watch">
  <div class="face">
    <div class="numbers"></div>
    <div class="hands">
      <div class="hand hand-hour"></div>
      <div class="hand hand-minute"></div>
      <div class="hand hand-second">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
We have to set the position of the numbers (in your code) inside JavaScript and I don't get it right. (Have a look at the picture in my edited question)

Comment: @CodingTil, I'll take a look at it and edit my answer when I get back home. By the way why do you want to add those lines in JavaScript, why not just add them in HTML?

Comment: Happy to help, I hope you learned something. If you have any questions regarding the CSS code or the JavaScript code don't hesitate to contact me via a comment.